# Can we pass regex alongside with replacement vector in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a string that a i need to replace with a replacement vector which i would like to use regex. is this thing possible?

```
txt='foo bar'
nchar(txt)
ix='foo'
gsub(ix,'bar', txt) #### output
gsub(pattern = '[^ix]', replacement = 'bar', txt)
```

Output desired is 'bar bar'

where ix is the char vector, how do i use pattern with regex is my real question.

Comment: What is the expected output?   `sub(paste0('^',ix), 'bar', txt)`

Comment: @akrun that makes sense. so i guess i have to use paste when passing in a vector. but can i also give more complicated regex in paste?

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli  Yes, you can use complicated regex with paste.

Comment: @RichardScriven i want to match ix with other regex character so that i get what im looking for. bascially i want to replace everything except ix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste` to join or a string object with another string.

```
sub(paste0('^',ix), 'bar', txt)
#[1] "bar bar"
```

NOTE: Using `^` inside `[` i.e. `'[^ix]'` have different meaning.